# Environment delimited by a lfloor-like bar

Tags: environments

I'm trying to reproduce the picture below: I want an environment with 1 parameter for the title (on the picture: "Définition 35" or "Définition 36") which is always bold and underlined, and the content of the environment (text, maths, or whatever) is displayed in a sort of lfloor sign below.
Also, the horizontal part of the lfloor-like sign on the left never changes its length, only the vertical left bar adjusts its height to the height of the text (see picture below).

I wasn't able to find something anywhere (probably because of my broken english -- and I hope I'm even understandable ! ...), and I really hope someone will be able to help me !

Thanks !

[image: lfloor environment to reproduce]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SX!

This is an approach with `tikz` and `environ` packages.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{environ}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcounter{Defin}
\newsavebox{\DefTitleBox}
\newsavebox{\DefBox}
\NewEnviron{myDefi}{\refstepcounter{Defin}\savebox{\DefTitleBox}{\hbox{{\bfseries Definition \theDefin:\space}}}\savebox{\DefBox}{\parbox[t]{0.9\textwidth}{\BODY}}%
\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[ultra thick] (0,0)--(1.1\wd\DefTitleBox,0)node[midway, above]{\usebox\DefTitleBox};
\draw[ultra thick](3.5mm,0)--(3.5mm,-{\dimexpr\ht\DefBox+\dp\DefBox+2\baselineskip})node[midway,right,shift={(3mm,0)}]{\usebox{\DefBox}};
\draw[ultra thick] (3.5mm,-{\dimexpr\ht\DefBox+\dp\DefBox+2\baselineskip}) --(0.7\wd\DefTitleBox,-{\dimexpr\ht\DefBox+\dp\DefBox+2\baselineskip});
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{myDefi}
Test definition 

\[f(x)=3\cdot x -5\]
\end{myDefi}

\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{myDefi}
Test definition

\[f(x)=3\cdot x -5\]
where $x$ is something\ldots
\end{myDefi}

\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Huge thanks for answering so quickly ! This is perfect ;-)

Comment: Welcome @user245225 ... Happy TeXing... If you wish you may use the check-mark next to my answer to accept it as a solution to your question.

Answer (score 3):

An easy way to do it is to use the package [thmtools](https://ctan.org/pkg/thmtools). It provides commands to put boxes around theorems, and one of the predefined box styles seems to be the same as in your example.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\declaretheorem[name=Définition, thmbox=M]{definition}
\begin{document}
\begin{definition}
Si \(E\) et \(F\) sont deux ensembles, l'ensemble de toutes les applications de \(E\) dans \(F\) est noté \(\mathcal{F}(E,F)\) ou encore \(F^E\).
\end{definition}
\end{document}
```